# Socket appender to write logs into ELK logstash

Tags: java, log4j, elastic-stack

I've created log4j.properties file with below values that uses socket appender to route logs to Esaas. But none of the logs are written into logstash.

```
log4j.appender.logstash=org.apache.log4j.net.SocketAppender
log4j.appender.logstash.RemoteHost=esaashost.somecompany.intranet
log4j.appender.logstash.port=65433
log4j.appender.logstash.ReconnectionDelay=60000
log4j.appender.logstash.LocationInfo=true
log4j.appender.socket.LocationInfo=true
log4j.appender.logstash.KeyStore.path=<<JKS location>>
log4j.appender.logstash.TrustStore.path=<<JKS location>>
log4j.appender.logstash.KeyStore.location=<<JKS location>>
log4j.appender.logstash.TrustStore.location=<<JKS location>>
log4j.appender.logstash.truststore.password=password
```

Since our Esaas server is hosted in intranet, I'm setting up the remote host, port, trust/ keystore file details etc.,. Do let me know if I'm missing something.

Then I use below code to write logs

```
Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ClassName.class);
logger.Info("Info Log");
```

Is the above code correct? Or, am I missing something/writing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

What version of ELK are you using? log4j socker appender does not work with logstash for some time.
[Deprecation notice](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-log4j.html)